# Thunderbird does not show all the folders I created from webmail

Tags: thunderbird

I am accessing office365.outlook.com. I used to use it the web version where I created some personal folders. Recently I started to use thunderbird mail client. It only shows inbox and sent items folders. Where are the rest of my folders?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Thunderbird, at the top of the folder tree is your account name (just above inbox).

Right click this and choose "Subscribe" - you should be presented with a list of folders, and you can choose which ones you want to see.