# Thunderbird not downloding new folders from webexchange

Tags: thunderbird

I use **Thunderbird 45.7.0** as mail client on my Ubuntu 16.10 for my **web-exchange** account. The first time I set Thunderbird up, all folders are synchronised. However, if I create new folders in Web-exchange with web-browser, the new created folders will not be downloaded to Thunderbird. What was the problem?

server type is IMAP/SMTP, and connection security is set to SSL/TLS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is found from another post,

[Thunderbird does not show all the folders I created from webmail](https://superuser.com/questions/1131219/thunderbird-does-not-show-all-the-folders-i-created-from-webmail?rq=1)